Scatter plot not updating propertly
I have a small problem updating a scatter plot.
Currently I have as the initialization command
ask small-agricultors [plotxy economic global]

For the updating i have the same code
ask small-agricultors [plotxy economic global]

However, the graph is not updating as I wanted because I thought that Updating meant that it would move the point to the new position, instead it placed new points (Top of the image) How do I tell netlogo to just move the points? or delete the previous ones?


the clear-plot command is probably what you are looking for (see here). Note that: "This command will produce a runtime error if the current plot has not been set.", so you will have to set the desired plot with set-current-plot if you don't do it already (see here).
to plotting
  set-current-plot "plot 1"
  clear-plot
  set-current-plot-pen "default"
  set-plot-pen-mode 2 

  ask n-of 5 patches [plotxy pxcor pycor]
end


Sorry but it still doesnt work as it suppossed to. I placed the clear-plot command first

´´´´clear-plot
ask cattles [plotxy economic global]´´´

not sure what's the problem in your case, but I added a minimal example. I hope it helps to understand how to solve your problem. Otherwise I would need more details what exactly is not working in your case.
